# Trying to install R cmdr I get an unexpected error message. What's wrong?

Tags: 15.10, r

The terminal states:

```
Error in .chooseMirror(m, "CRAN", graphics, ind, useHTTPS) : 
  could not find function "setNames"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you get solution to this error?
I have run into the same problem after upgrading R from 3.0.1 to 3.2.2

Comment: @shiv said: Did you get solution to this error? I have run into the same problem after upgrading R from 3.0.1 to 3.2.2.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/689061/edit) your question and indicate how you are installing R. Are you installing from standard repositories, PPAs, or from R's web page?

Comment: Does http://askubuntu.com/a/739022/511498 work for you?
reprint for min length:
Try using `R --vanilla` - an .Rprofile can break it - mine does...