# Problem in installing packages in R

Tags: 14.04, r

In R, I am trying to run -

```
install.package('rattle')
```

but terminal gives me following error -

```
Error in .chooseMirror(m, "CRAN", graphics, ind, useHTTPS) : 
could not find function "setNames"
```

R version - 3.2.2
Ubuntu - 14.04 LTS

**How to solve this error?**

Maybe because I had few problems during installation of R-base -

From Command Line, It would only install 3.0.2, but not 3.2.2.
Hence, I installed R-3.2.2 from Ubuntu software centre.

From Software centre, it would not install r-base, and give following ERROR :

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
he following packages have unmet dependencies:

r-base: Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.2.2-1trusty0) but 3.2.2-1trusty0 is to be installed
Depends: r-recommended (= 3.2.2-1trusty0) but 3.0.2-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

So after that, from software center I tried first installing r-base-core-1trusty0, and then r-base-1trusty0.
It worked and I had R-3.2.2 installed in system.

While installing a package from R, by install.packages(), It ask me to choose a mirror. After choosing mirror, I get the above error. stating problem in .chooseMirror(...)

I get the same error of .chooseMirror, When I try -

```
update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE)
```

Maybe the error could be due to installation problems

P.S: I am reposting this question after making edit on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689061/trying-to-install-r-cmdr-i-get-an-unexpected-error-message-whats-wrong) question because don't have enough reputation points to comment on others post.

Comment: I also use 14.04, I installed R-3.2.3 through command line. It seems to be like an messy installation. Anyway, can you purge your current R setup(backup your conf files, if any) & try out this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-r-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `R --vanilla` - an .Rprofile can break it - mine does...